# Same command in substitution doesn't work

Tags: bash

This works:

```
cat f.txt 2>&1
```

But this doesn't:

```
c="cat f.txt 2>&1" && `$c`
cat: '2>&1': No such file or directory
```

Why?

Comment: That's not the same command. `c="cat f.txt 2>&1"; $c` would have the same problem, and has no command substitution involved anywhere. See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: ...that said, using backticks for command substitution *does* change meaning of backslashes within, so you should use the more modern (standardized with the publication of POSIX.2 in 1991) syntax of `$( )` instead.